'npx drizzle-kit generate' command not updateing schema for SQLite
Need some help with drizzle orm. I'm using sqlite with drizzle orm, in the schema i have one table. i generated migration files from it. But when i added a new column in the existing table and tried to generate a new migration it says "No schema changes, nothing to migrate" even though i did add a new column in the table. Why is it happening ? Am doing something wrong or is there any conditions to do it.
First Schema:
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";
import { text, integer, sqliteTable } from "drizzle-orm/sqlite-core";
export const users = sqliteTable('users', {
  id: text('id'),
});


After adding a new column:
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";
import { text, integer, sqliteTable } from "drizzle-orm/sqlite-core";
export const users = sqliteTable('users', {
  id: text('id'),
  name: text('name')
});

I generated migration files from the first schema afterward I added a new column that you can see at the second scheme and after that tried to generate a new migration file, but it says 'No schema changes, nothing to migrate ', even though I added a new column on the second schema. But the key point is that it's only happening with SQLite. Though it works perfectly with PostgreSQL.
Drizzle-kit should detect the changes on the schema for SQLite.

Using Drizzle with SQLite and it picks up schema changes for me.  If you look in the migrations folder, and look at the meta folder, is the name field already in that bit?.
